# Show that $ f $ is totally differentiable with continuous Jacobi matrix

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $ f: \mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ with
$
f(x, y)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
x y \frac{x^{2}-y^{2}}{x^{2}+y^{2}} & :(x, y) \neq(0,0) \\
0 & :(x, y)=(0,0)
\end{array}\right.
$

Show that $ f $ is totally differentiable with continuous Jacobi matrix.

**Edit**:
To show the total differentiability, look separately at the two cases for $ = (0,0) $ and $ \ne (0,0) $:

For $ (x,y) \ne (0,0) $: is really easy to show, because first there is a continuous fct. because of the composition of continuous fcts, then you can determine the two partial derivatives -> Then you have already a continuously partially differentiable function and then there is a theorem that you can directly deduce the total differentiability from the continuous partial differentiability of the function in $\mathbb{R^2}\backslash \{(0,0)\}$.

For $ (x,y) = (0,0) $: is also partial differential, but I get stuck at the continuity.

Moreover, I do not quite understand the last part with the Jacobi matrix.

First: does my above consideration make sense?

Second: can someone help me with the continuity in the (0,0) case and explain to me what is meant by the Jacobi matrix?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That $f(x+h_1,y+h_2)=f(x,y)+\left<\nabla f(x,y),(h_1,h_2)^T\right>+o(\|(h_1,h_2)^T\|)$ for all $x,y\in \mathbb R$.

Comment: What is your definition of total differentiability? Where in that definition does the Jacobi matrix appear? Go from there. Your task is *first* to show that this function is in fact totally differentiable. And *then* to show that its Jacobi matrix (which is a matrix valued function on the domain of $f$) is a continuous function.